# How do I fade in/out a jQuery menu with sub menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am trying to make a menu that has many links and each link has its own sublist, this is what I am using

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".users").bind("click", function() {
    $('#menu').fadeOut();
    $('#sub_menu').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">
    <li>users <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>product <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>movies <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>clips <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>teaser <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>trailer <br /></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#">
    <li>HDMovie <br /></a>
  </li>
</div>
```

This is only for the users link to show its sublist.  If i want to do the same with product, movies, and clips links do I have to copy and paste the function?  Can anyone here give me a example of a function so i don't have to copy paste?

Thanks ;)

Comment: As noted by bendewey, your existing HTML is not correct. The correct tag order would be: <a href="#"><li>users</li></a><br />. This still has issues, but at least the tags are properly nested. Look in to using an actual list rather than line breaks.

Comment: You really don't need <a> tags at all. I wish I knew more about what your sub_menu looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would use the [Superfish](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Superfish) plugin and not reinvent the wheel.  Combine it with [hoverIntent](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) and it should be able to do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fo replie guys, i have used this function it is working it fades out my menu and also fadesIn the sub menu but the same sub menu for every link i want sub menu2 to fadeIn when i click the next link..

Here is the link what i am doing http://umarstudio.com/test/html/screen_2b.htm

I just need the submenus to fade In for every link.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.  Also, make sure your properly ending your nested tags

```
<body>
<ul id="products" class="menu">
<li><a href="#">users</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu'>
        <li><a href="#">user 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">user 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">user 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">product</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu'>
        <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">movies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">clips</a></li>
<li><a href="#">teaser</a></li>
<li><a href="#">trailer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HDMovie</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu > li > a").bind("click", function(){
        $('.sub_menu').fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().find('.sub_menu').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

Comment: hi,
thanks fo replies, i have used this function it is working it fades out my menu and also fadesIn the sub menu but the same sub menu for every link i want sub menu2 to fadeIn when i click the next link..
                 
         Thanks guys...

Comment: I just need the submenus to fade In for every link.. Thanks ;)